# Problem converting Python np.ndarray (image) to C++ Mat using Cython

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, cython

I have written a function that efficiently loops through a **grayscale** image pixels using C++. The key was using pointers to image rows/columns instead of regular pixel access.

The C++ logic looks like this:

```
Mat image = imread(image_path); //path for the image
for (int j = 0; j < rawDepth.rows; j++)
{
    const ushort* Mi = rawDepth.ptr<ushort>(j); //pointer to the current column
    for (int i = 0; i < rawDepth.cols; i++)
    {
       ushort pixelValue = Mi[i]; //value of the pixel
    }
}
```

This method is extremely fast but I need it running on Python. I was able to successfully rewrite it using Cython but now I am stuck with the problem of getting pointers to columns in numpy nd arrays.

My image is stored in a 2D numpy array(I read it using cv2)

I have been trying to efficiently convert my image from an np array to a structure similar to the C++ Mat object that would give me the same efficiency.

I have tried several approaches that I found online but none of them seem to work. I am using Python 3.6.6 and Cython 0.28.5

Thanks

Edit: I was able to implement the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25382316/10664643). I now have a cpp file where I can call the nparrayToMat() function from my pyx file.

However, I can't seem to be able to access the .ptr function of Mat.

I would appreciate if someone can point out how to do this.

Comment: See OpenCV sources, efficiently converting between a numpy array and C++ Mat is what it does in the Python wrappers all the time.

Comment: Use `cv2.imread()` in Python and you can access the image you read directly as a Numpy array. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079022/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah that is whatI already do. I do have the image as a Numpy array but I need it as a Mat object so I can use pointers to columns.