# Counting a certain pixel value in Python

Tags: python, image, pixel

How can I count the number of pixels in Python when Gray value = 1 and gray value = 100 in an RGB image?

Comment: RGB images have 3 values for each pixel, 1 for red, 1 for green and 1 for blue, so please clarify what you really want. Also, please share your image and your latest/greatest code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

A pixel is somewhere between white and black (and shades of gray are inbetween) if the three values for R, G and B are equal. Assuming 8 bit values:

(0,0,0) -> black
(80,80,80) -> dark gray
(160,160,160) -> light gray
(255,255,255) -> white

I think you get the point. Now all you need to do is to iterate over the picture, line for line and within that pixel for pixel and evaluate the color to eventually count it.

There may be functions creating [histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Applications) that are optimized in this direction already.

Comment: Iterating over images line for line with Python is a really poor idea, IMHO.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079022/2836621

Comment: Somehow I believe the numpy solution follows the same algorithm. Or is there some clever alternative? But I totally acknowledge that doing the same in (interpreted) python is slower than having a solution in optimized machine language directly.